# Select records with two data on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql and I have a search function that you can search through ranging the prices. Textbox1 for minimum price and textbox2 for maximum price.

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE PRICE_T (ITEM VARCHAR2(255),PRICE_MIN VARCHAR2(6) , PRICE_MAX VARCHAR2(6) );
```

Values :

```
INSERT INTO PRICE_T VALUES ('BOTTLE','450', '450');  
INSERT INTO PRICE_T VALUES ('GUNDAM','500','600');  
INSERT INTO PRICE_T VALUES ('CUP','2700', '4000');  
INSERT INTO PRICE_T VALUES ('BEEF','500','700');
```

If I input 0 for price min and 2000 for price max.
All of  these records should appear at output. But I am only getting one.

This is my code :

```
SELECT * FROM PRICE_T 
WHERE 
            (
                0 BETWEEN PRICE_MIN AND PRICE_MAX 
            )
        OR  (
                2000 BETWEEN PRICE_MIN AND PRICE_MAX 
            )
```

How to select records using two data between two columns?

Comment: why are you storing your numbers as varchar?

Comment: Storing numbers as varchar is going to cause you problems sooner rather than later.. Reconsider your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused with your where clause.
It should be

```
SELECT * FROM PRICE_T
WHERE
(CAST(PRICE_MIN AS DECIMAL(18,2)) BETWEEN 0 AND 2000)
OR
(CAST(PRICE_MAX AS DECIMAL(18,2)) BETWEEN 0 AND 2000)
```

Why do you have string prices btw

(When you do change your table structure to not have varchar prices, you don't need to cast it to decimal. simply go with

```
SELECT * FROM PRICE_T
WHERE
(PRICE_MIN BETWEEN 0 AND 2000)
OR
(PRICE_MAX BETWEEN 0 AND 2000)
```

Comment: Ohh i see. Okay i will change it  to integer. and thank you for the answer. this works perfectly!!